# Laravel Vite get Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined when import custom js file

Tags: jquery, vite, laravel-10, laravel-vite

I use Laravel with Vite, and import my custom js file in app.js like this.

```
import jQuery from "jquery";
Object.assign(window, {$: jQuery, jQuery})
window.jQuery = window.$ = $

import "./custom.js"
```

in my `custom.js` file, only this content.

```
$('body').html("jquery work!")
```

But get error `app.9618bc24.js:104 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

If I comment the `import "./custom.js"` line. I still can use `$('body').html("jquery work!")` in blade. That mean Jquery is loaded, right? But why it not work in custom.js file?

I know I can use jquery in `app.js`, but I have too many script, I must split the code to `custom.js`. Help me, please.

Comment: did you solve this? i am getting so frustrated with vite and custom js today

Answer (score 0):

When you import "./custom.js" separately, it's in a different module scope, and it doesn't automatically recognize the global $ variable defined in app.js.

Try the following...

**custom.js**

```
import $ from "jquery";

$('body').html("jquery work!");
```